# c# cachedependency dispose pattern

Tags: c#, dispose, cache-dependency

I am adding objects of cache dependency to an array of such AggregateCacheDependency. when I finish with the array I dispose it. my question is do I have to dispose just the array containing the objects or do I have to dispose of the objects them self before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don need explicitly dispose the objects within AggregateCacheDependency as it hendles disposal of its objects itself. Here is the metohod of AggregateCacheDependency which disposes each object in its array:

```
protected override void DependencyDispose()
        {
            CacheDependency[] array = null;
            bool flag = false;
            try
            {
                Monitor.Enter(this, ref flag);
                this._disposed = true;
                if (this._dependencies != null)
                {
                    array = (CacheDependency[])this._dependencies.ToArray(typeof(CacheDependency));
                    this._dependencies = null;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (flag)
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(this);
                }
            }
            if (array != null)
            {
                CacheDependency[] array2 = array;
                for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
                {
                    CacheDependency cacheDependency = array2[i];
                    cacheDependency.DisposeInternal();
                }
            }
        }
```